# unable to display array result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I got the following array. now I get the single records but when is their array records then it doesn't work. I tried with OR condition but it doesn't work.

```
$this->db->get_where('genre',array('genre_id'=>$row['genre_id']))->row()->name;
//I get Follwoing Records
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [movie_id] => 7
        [title] => Raaz
        [genre_id] => 8 // it display the name
        [actors] => []
        [trailer_url] => https://drive.google.com/
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [movie_id] => 8
        [title] => Tribute
        [genre_id] => ["2","5","20"] // it doesn't display the name
        [actors] => []
        [trailer_url] => https://drive.google.com/
    )
```

I tried the following code

```
$this->db->get_where('genre',array('genre_id'=>$row['genre_id']))->row()->name;
```

above code works for 0 index but it doesn't work 1 index array

Comment: [check function or_where_in()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html)

Comment: @Mohammad: but it will not work with get_where,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where_in` but you can't use it with `get_where`, you need to use alternate here instead of `get_where`:

**Example:**

You can alternate here like:

```
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->from('genre');
if(is_array($row['genre_id'])){ // if result is in array
    $this->db->where_in('genre_id',$row['genre_id']);    
}
else{ // for single record.
    $this->db->where('genre_id',$row['genre_id']);
}
$query = $this->db->get();
print_r($query->result_array()); // will generate result in an array
```

**Edit:**

After debugging, you are getting this value `["2","5","20"]` as a string, so you can modify this code:

```
$genreID = intval($row['genre_id']); // 
if($genreID > 0){ 
    $this->db->where('genre_id',$row['genre_id']);    
}
else{ 
   $genreID = json_decode($row['genre_id'],true);
   $this->db->where_in('genre_id',$genreID);    
}
```

**[CI Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)**

Comment: it works fine with single data but it doesn't work with array values

Comment: @nadygold: what are u getting?

Comment: for single i get
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Comedy
        )

)  but in array i get blank

Comment: i just print the query that i get following for array
SELECT `name` FROM `genre` WHERE `genre_id` = '[\"2\",\"5\",\"20\"]'

Comment: run this query in your phpmyadmin and chk if u r getting result `SELECT name FROM genre WHERE genre_id IN (2,5,20)` @nadygold

Comment: @nadygold: it means, second conditions is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190856/discussion-between-devpro-and-nady-gold).

Comment: Thanks Man you help me a lot

Comment: @nadygold: glad to help u